# How to print public key from certificates using "cryptography" library in Python2?

Tags: python, cryptography, certificate, x509certificate

I have to extract public key from .pem certificate using cryptography library in Python2 but am able to get only public key object .

In cryptography documentation , I found this code

```
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import rsa

pem_cert=open("/home/lab14/aes/fd.pem","rb").read()

cert = x509.load_pem_x509_certificate(pem_cert, default_backend())

public_key = cert.public_key()

print(public_key)
```

But when run this, I get public key object but not actual key in hex format.

Here is the output I got

```
<cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.rsa._RSAPublicKey object at 0x7f49e214d6d8>
```

Any assistance would be helpful and appreciated .
Thank you

Comment: An RSA public consists of two (usually large) numbers. There is no obvious representation as a single hexadecimal string.

Answer (score 2):

You don't really say what you want to print or why. If you just wanted to print the public exponent and modulus of an RSAPublicKey you can do:

```
public_key = cert.public_key()
print((public_key.public_numbers().e, public_key.public_numbers().n))
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got a public key *object*, which needs to be encoded to retrieve a representation of the key in bytes. Then those bytes can be encoded using any hexadecimal encoder - if that's what is required.

So simply call `public_bytes(encoding, format)` to retrieve the bytes. The encoding can be `SubjectPublicKeyInfo`, which contains information about the public key type (it's a generic key) or `PKCS1`, which basically contains a minimal encoding of the RSA public key. Note that you may first have to establish the key type before you can use `PKCS1` because that only describes RSA keys.

You can also choose between DER and PEM format. DER just returns a byte representation of the ASN.1 defined structure of an RSA public key. PEM base 64 encodes that structure and adds header and footer lines as to create a textual representation of the key.